# How to set a defaultChecked to only first input in radio button when using map function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use defaultChecked in reactjs when using map function to only one radio button. But How can I acomplish it?

```
{colors.map((color, index) => {
      return (
        <label className="color-checkmark" key={index}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            checked="checked"
            name="color"
            value={color}
            // defaultChecked
          />
        </label>
      );
    })}
```

If I use defaultChecked there it will be set to every radio button.

Comment: which item do you want checked by default?

Comment: First item to be checked by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `checked="checked"` attribute as it conflicts with the `defaultChecked` attribute. And then add `defaultChecked={index === 0}`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the first item checked

```
{colors.map((color, index) => {
  return (
    <label className="color-checkmark" key={index}>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="color"
        value={color}
        defaultChecked={!(!!index)}
      />
    </label>
  );
})}
```

what does `!!` do?

the `!!` ensures that the value will always be a boolean or converted to a boolean.

Comment: This didn't work. It just checked every radio button.

Comment: using the index?

Comment: yes using index also it just set every radio button as checked in HTML DOM.

Comment: see the code above and remove `checked="checked"` from the input.

Comment: you don't actually need to do `!(!!index)` in this case, since it's a zero index, you can do `!index` and it will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a condition to your `defaultChecked`, and remove the `checked` property:

```js
const colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red']

function App() {
  return colors.map((color, index) => (
    <label key={index}>
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="color"
        value={color}
        defaultChecked={index === 0}
      />
      <span style={{color}}>{color}</span>
    </label>
  ))
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">euoeu</div>
```

Comment: I just want my first radio button to be checked by default without any criteria.

Comment: I updated my answer then. You need to set defaultChecked only if index === 0. Don't forget to remove the `checked` property you put in your example.

Comment: It does for me, see the example. It means you forgot something, check again.